# Inject an API Returned JSON Into <li> Materialized.css JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, materialize

I am currently building a JS based website using Materialized CSS framework.
I am new to JS and learning through the process.

I have this HTML code:

```html
 <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion" ng-controller="web">
    <li id = "event">
      <div class="collapsible-header">
       <div class="col s4 " id = "city"><i class="material-icons">info</i> {{event.city}}</div> 
       <div class="col s4 "><i class="material-icons">query_builder</i> time</div> 
       <div class="col s4 "><i class="material-icons">location_on</i> place</div>  
     </div>
     <div class="collapsible-body">
      <p>
        <div class="col s12 "> Infornation about the event </div> 
      </p>
       <div class="right-align">
          <input type="checkbox" id="test5" class="right-align" />
          <label for="test5"> Attend </label> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

The data is coming from a JSON i get from an API call.
The JSON looks like this:

```css
[
{"city": "Tel Aviv-Yafo",
  "event_url": "http://www....",
  "attendees": 167, "description": "Dear SpeedMinders,... ",
  "price": "free", "host": "Bella Miller",
  "address": "Yigal Alon 98, Electra Tower,34 Floor, Events Zone Space",
  "date": 1440914400000,
  "id": 6036899730817024,
  "name": "Fast Track to Innovation (FTI) - \u20ac 3 Million opportunity for EU funding"
},
...
]
```

I want to create a list of 10 events (each one is li tag).
In Such way that i could iterate the list from the JS itself.

I have a AJAX call to get the JSON, I can't seem to find a way to show the returned JSON in any way:

```js
(function($){
 $(function(){
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  $('.parallax').parallax();
   getlist();
  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space


var eventlist = [];
var name = 'ita';
function getlist()
{
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://attender-mobile.appspot.com/api',
  type: "GET",
  data: "",
  contentType: "json",
  dataType: "jsonp text",
  complete: function (data) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
   eventlist = data;    
  }
 });
document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

The line:

> alert(JSON.stringify(result));

just shows

> {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}

I am finding it hard to find out which tools i need to do this, and how to start doing this.

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can we see the code for `renderList()` at first glance you might have an issue rendering the list with that method outside of the `complete` callback. You need to render it once the data is received. Since AJAX is asynchronous, eventList will probably be empty at the time it's passed to `renderList()`. Call `renderList(eventList, 0)` inside the complete callback.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz I have edited the question, i dont use renderList().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ which explain how to retrieve JSON using ajax.

Since your are learning I'll give you a tip or two:
1) your dataType parameter: does it contain the correct value?
2) wouldn't you rather use the success parameter instead of the complete parameter?

Comment: for some reason it works from a local json file but not from server